# What is the Bene Gesserit’s “message for humankind”?

Tags: dune

In *Chapterhouse Dune,* one of the [encyclopedia exposita](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EncyclopediaExposita) entries at the beginning of a chapter is (boldface mine):

> Our household god is this thing we carry forward generation after generation: **our message for humankind if it matures**. The closest thing we have to a household goddess is a failed Reverend Mother—Chenoeh there in her niche.
>
> —Darwi Odrade

While I am aware that maturing humanity is a central goal of the Bene Gesserit, I cannot remember any other mention of the Bene Gesserit’s message for humanity in Frank Herbert’s books. I might have missed something though and I’ve not read anything not written by Frank Herbert. Thus my question is: **Is this message ever mentioned again or are its contents elaborated?**

Comment: I don't think this is a literal message, as in a single pithy revelation. I think it's the accumulated wisdom of the BG sisterhood--everything they've learned (or decided) about what it means to **be** a mature humankind. As such, the "message" amounts to everything we know the BG (and, incidentally, the Tyrant) actually cared about.

Comment: Here is another analysis of BG: "The basic rule is this: Never support weakness: always support strength. - The Bene Gesserit Azhar Book, Compilation of Great Secrets" - https://books.google.com/books/about/Heretics_of_Dune.html?id=0ZKAkX0W4A4C

Comment: I've thought the Bene Geserit were their own message.  They wished all "humans" to be as "human" as they were.